# How do I show that $n=2$ is the only integer satisfy :$\cos^n\theta+ \sin^n\theta=1$ for all $\theta$ real or complex?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, proof-explanation, pythagorean-triples

It is well known that :$\cos²\theta+ \sin²\theta=1$ for all $\theta$ real or complex ,I would like to ask about the general equality :$\cos^n\theta+ \sin^n\theta=1$ if there is others values of the positive integer $n$ than $n=2$ for which : $$\cos^n\theta+ \sin^n\theta=1$$ for all $\theta$ real or complex ?

probably the equivalent question is to ask this question :

**Question**:How do I show that  $n=2$ is the only integer satisfy :$$\cos^n\theta+ \sin^n\theta=1$$ for all $\theta$ real or complex ?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 8):

Let $\theta=\pi/4$ and evaluate.

Comment: How does this prove it $\forall \  \theta\ \in \ \rm C$?

Comment: and that is the problem

Comment: @Tim an equation is not satisfied $\forall \theta\in\mathbb{C}$ if it's not satisfied for some special case $\theta =\pi/4\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @kamil09875 yes but thats for disproving! for proving, we cant take specific $\theta$ if we are proving something, as it is an identity in $\theta$

Comment: @Tim Chris just proved that this equation is not satisfied $\forall \theta$ when $n\ne 2$. I think it is easy for now to show that is is satisfied $\forall \theta$ when $n=2$. It follows that $n=2$ is the only solution

Answer (score 2):

Try differentiating both sides:
$$\begin{align}\sin^nx+\cos^nx &= 1 \\ 
\implies \frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin^nx+\cos^nx\right) &= 0
\\ n(\sin x)^{n-1} \cos x-n(\cos x)^{n-1}\sin x&=0 \\
(\tan x)^{n-1}&=\tan x \\\end{align}$$

$$ \implies n-1=1 \\ {n = 2}$$

Comment: if x is a  complex number , could you keep the same way for derivative of both sides ? if yes , then it is a nice answer and perfect

Comment: i didn't assume $x\in \rm R$, so i think it should work for any $x \in C$. But i am not too sure about it.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik yes, it does work for complex numbers too

Comment: yes , i know how only to show it works with $n=2 $, as  :$cos²z+sin²z=(cosz+isin z)(cosz-isin z) ={e}^{iz}{e}^{-iz}=1 $, but to show that is only $n=2$ in the complex case i don't sure for that !!!

Comment: @zeraouliarafik When you posted the comment above, a full answer was on the page for 2.5 hours. Please explain.